# Restrict AWS API GATEWAY to specific a AWS account

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

We want to restrict our REST API to specific a AWS account. 
Not a to a specific user in the account but all users and resources in the account.

I have tried this resource policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "MY_API_ARN/*/*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:userId": "*MY_ACCOUNT_NUMBER*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The API should be reachable from a lambda or a EC2 inside the AWS account but not from outside.

**Important** : If possible I would like to avoid restricting the API to a VPC.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need try to use `aws:SourceAccount` for you condition:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:*:a123456789/test/POST/mydemoresource/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceAccount": "a123456789"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks we tried it. We had to add a principal. It blocks outside calls but also calls from lambda